# Sublime Text's Terminus is not displaying Oh My Zsh icons

Tags: zsh, sublimetext, oh-my-zsh

I get a generic `?` where the icons should be.

A similar issue but for Visual Studio Code is documented here:
https://dev.to/avantar/how-to-fix-zsh-icons-in-visual-studio-code-terminal-38bb

Needless to say, I haven't been able to find an equivalent fix.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by setting `"font_face": "MesloLGS NF"`, the preferred font of the powerlevel10k theme.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [@ctrebbau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17763665/ctrebbau). That worked.

I added this to Terminus Sublime Settings, and then restarted Sublime. That fixed it.

```
{
    "view_settings": {
        "font_face": "MesloLGS NF"
    }
}
```